# Regular expressions | Extracting dates from text

Tags: regex, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to extract dates from several articles. When I test the regular expression the pattern match only part of the information of interest. As you can see:
https://regex101.com/r/ATgIeZ/2

This is a sample of the text file:

```
|[<p>Advertisement ,   By  MILAN SCHREUER  and     ALISSA J. RUBIN    OCT. 5, 2016 
 ,  BRUSSELS — A man wounded two police officers with a knife in Brussels around...] 3004
[<p>Advertisement ,   By   DAVID JOLLY    FEB. 8, 2016 
 ,  KABUL, Afghanistan — A  Taliban  suicide bomber killed at least three people on Mo JULY 14, 2034
```

The extraction pattern that I am using and the code is this one:

```
import re 

text_open = open("News_cleaned_definitive.csv")
text_read = text_open.read()
pattern = ("[A-Z]+\.*\s(\d+)\,\s(\d+){4}")
result = re.findall(pattern,text_read)
print(result)
```

And the output from Anaconda is:

```
[('5', '6'), ('7', '5'), ('1', '6'), .....]
```

The expected output is:

```
OCT. 5, 2016, FEB. 8, 2016, JULY 14, 2034 .....
```

Comment: the groups between parentheses match only digits. What is the expected output (also, your regex on regextester is different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the repeat command `{4}` which is outside your last group. Also, the regex to capture the month was not within a group

Fix it like this:

```
pattern = r"([A-Z]+)\.?\s(\d+)\,\s(\d{4})"
```

result with your data sample:

```
[('OCT', '5', '2016'), ('FEB', '8', '2016'), ('JULY', '14', '2034')]
```

Small extra fixes:

- there can be 0 or 1 dot. So removed `\.*` for `\.?`
- used "raw" prefix, always better when defining regexes string (no problems here, but can happen with `\b` for instance)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I would like to extract also the month (FEB., JULY etc.)

Comment: I have the date in the format of  1ST JULY 2018 , I have to search it from paragraph and write it as 01/07/2018 , is it possible dudu @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: sounds like another question. But with my answer you should be able to do so by stripping off all the non-numeric stuff and change the order or words

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, it helped to understand the use of parenthesis in regex.
I solved my self with this:

```
pattern=("([A-Z]+\.*\s)(\d+)\,\s(\d{4})")
```